# Use Http POST and GET to navigate a website

Tags: java, android

I want my android app to establish a connection to a website and through code navigate the website in background. From what I understand, the first step is to get html source code of the site I wish to navigate which I managed to do through this code:

```
public class HttpTest extends Activity {
private TextView tvCode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.http_layout);  

    tvCode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHTMLCode);
    String s = null;
    try {
        GetHtmlSourceCode html = new GetHtmlSourceCode();
        html.execute("http://www.youtube.com");
        s = html.get();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tvCode.setText("Error");
    }
    if (s != null)
        tvCode.setText(s);

}

private class GetHtmlSourceCode extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String content = "";

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

            int data = in.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char c = (char) data;
                data = in.read();
                content += c;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

}

(Youtube is used just as an example).
After getting the source code from youtube.com, I want my app to input something in the search box and then click the search button.
From what I understand I need to send a POST request to youtube to fill the search box, another POST to press the button and finally a GET to get the html source code of the page with the search result. However the deprecation of the HttpClient and HttpPost classes with which these problems appear to have been solved, my limited english vocabulary and my general ignorance on the subject make it very difficult to find the solution myself.
Can someone help?

Comment: If you want to download the whole pages and links in a site, I recommend you to take a look at **webzip**.

Comment: @Salivan I do not want to download the whole page. I just want to navigate them through code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private HttpResponse response;
    private String responseString ;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {


        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else{

                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //TO Do
    }
}
```

To make request, use the following code

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://yourwebsite.com");
```